# Console errors when ajax URL failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jsonp

I'm trying to get video information from Youtube and Dailymotion video URLs. When I pass a wrong URL in to ajax, it gives errors in console.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="addUrl">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#addUrl').on('keyup', function () {
    $url = $(this).val();
    $updatedUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + $youtubeVideoId + '?v=2&alt=json';

    $.ajax({
        url: $updatedUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {

            //If the video URL is Youtube...
            if ($url.indexOf("youtube") >= 0) {
                var title = data.entry.title.$t;
                var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
                var thumbnail = '<img src="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + '"alt=""/>';
            }

            //If the video URL is Dailymotion...
            if ($url.indexOf("dailymotion") >= 0) {.....
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Invalid action');
        }
    });
});
```

If I placed the if condition before the `$.ajax` I don't see any console errors when wrong input. I need to keep the `if` inside the success function only.

How can I pass a validation message without console errors if it went wrong?

Comment: Cuold you explain better what your problem is , what you have done now and what you expect to achieve ?

Comment: Well... when $updatedUrl holds a wrong URL, I need to give a error message and prevent the console errors

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you are expecting to achieve and how,
but here's a small fiddle code that detects the inputted url string
and calls `$.ajax` only if "youtube" or "dailymotion" strings are detected.

This will prevent you from calling ajax each time the `keyup` event is triggered.

Also - you should define the type of request you want to make with `$.ajax` , like `POST` or `GET`.

I'm using a simple function here

```
function updateURL( updatedUrl, video ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: updatedUrl,
    type:"POST", //verify this method
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {

        //If the video URL is Youtube...
        if ( video == "yt") {
            var title = data.entry.title.$t;
            var description = data.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
            var thumbnail = '<img src="' + data.entry.media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url + '"alt=""/>';
        }

        //If the video URL is Dailymotion...
        if ( video == "dm") {
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Invalid action');
    }
});
```

}

Feel free to modify it to whatever you need.

Hope this helps:
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jz6k7ga/)